# Installed new LED transformer with spring terminal, light won't turn on

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

Transformer:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AcPLA2Pc8bgubRKxyaK6iwiYcjKNx6BZ/view?usp=drivesdk

LED light:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1A_YCzH6FLdCCPRd5q3_LZW30tqzxeZZ5/view?usp=drivesdk

Things I've tried:

- ensure cabling is tight
- ensure main is working by using an old transformer and halogen light
- LED light is working, tested in another socket
- swap the main phase & neutral cable (order doesn't matter?)
- swap the LED cable

I feel I'm doing something wrong but couldn't figure out what

Update:

I wonder if I didn't properly secure the cable. This is what the hole look like. There's no tiny screw that squeeze the cable. I thought screwing the one big screw at the corner is enough?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B5ZAns52IIxpQfNHN96DVvtETfw3M0Eg/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: what is the output voltage?

Comment: The markings say 11.3v AC

Comment: What is your input voltage ? Transformer says 220-240v. If you're powering it up with 120 volts it won't work.

Comment: Input voltage is 240v (Australia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if I didn't properly secure the cable. This is what the hole look like. There's no tiny screw that squeeze the cable. I thought screwing the one big screw at the corner is enough?

These are spring terminals. The wire is squeezed tight in place by the force of a spring. They're very reliable if used properly... there is no screw to get loose.

First, prepare your wire, check the manual for how much to strip, and if it is flexible wire, make sure to turn the strands between your fingers to make it nice and tight, like this random pic from the net. There should be no loose strands...

[image]

Use a small screwdriver blade to **gently** push down the tiny pushbutton on the terminals:

[image]

Don't push it sideways or it might break! Pushing it down releases the spring, and you can stick the wire into the hole, then release the pushbutton. Pull on the wire, it should not come out.

If you want to take the wire out, push the button and pull the wire.

If you use solid core wire then you don't need to push the button to stick the wire in. Solid core will find its way in.

Comment: Aha.. that must be it! I'll give it a try, thanks.